# Facebook is not working on Safari

Tags: safari, facebook

I am using Safari as Internet browser, and I noticed that Facebook does not autonomously load its contents when scrolling down. There are also other  quirks, e.g., the notification tab does not show any entry.

[image]

This only happens when visiting Facebook and only using Safari (both Google Chrome and Firefox do not show any issue).

Has this happened to someone before? Does someone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I don’t have this issue. Can you try disabling any extensions, opening a private window, and see if you can reproduce the issue?

Comment: @JBallin done, but still no changes. I've also reboot, but with no luck.

Comment: Are you using a vpn? Tried turning that off?

Comment: I am not using a VPN. I've still tried to disconnect and reconnect all my internet connections, but to no avail.

Comment: Sorry my suggestions haven’t been helpful! Last thing I would try is reviewing my safari settings and tinkering with them.

Comment: i use Safari to visit facebook and it works fine best i can tell.  i'm running high sierra 10.13.6 and latest version of safari.